# Is forcetk accessible in Communities

Tags: visualforce, attachment, community, forcetk

I am using `forcetk` to upload files (as `Attachment` records) in a `VisualForce Page` and it works fine. But when I access same page in a `Community`, I am not able to upload the file as I am getting the "503 Service Unavailable" in console. Is this proxy is accessible in communities?

Comment: Hi guys, with little bit of search came to know that request url has to be set in forcetk.Client(). So I used the clientId as null, loginUrl as login url for Community and proxyUrl as "services/proxy". When i tried with this request url is becoming -> "loginUrl/apex/services/proxy" instead of "loginUrl/services/proxy". Could you please let e know is there any way i can change this? 


Thanks

Comment: Was able to form the link but every time i am getting the "[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]" error. Please suggest.

Comment: I have the same problem when using AngularForce, which is a glue b/w AngularJS and ForceTK.

Comment: @ShrivathsKulkarni did you find a way around this? I'm currently faceing the same situation

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the URL of the Community reliably using the following Apex (and return it to the client using @AuraEnabled or @RemoteAction):

```
URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();
```

Then append the proxy/service endpoint to use in ForceTK or an XHR as your normally would

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this if you are willing to edit your copy of forcetk.js
https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/forcetk.js

find function: forcetk.Client.prototype.setSessionToken
leave it as is but at the end add:

```
this.instanceUrl = 'your community url';
this.proxyUrl = null;
this.visualforce = false;
```

This is a hack, there are ways to clean this up better, but this is the least intrusive modification I could pull off quickly.

I originally was using jsforce (which handles this nicely). Unfortunately, jsforce currently doesn't support IE9 so that's why I am here :)

Comment: This did not work for me. Does some other resolve this issue?

Comment: This should work @jonathanwiesel make sure you include the site prefix if you have one at the end of the instanceUrl: domain/site-prefix

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same Visualforce page to work in both a Community and outside a community, you need to construct the correct instance URL and proxy URL:

```
var elements = location.hostname.split(".");
var instance = (elements.length == 3) ? elements[0] : elements[1];
// Are we on a Community page?
var baseURL = '{!$Site.BaseUrl}' || null;
var proxy = '/services/proxy';
var instanceURL =  baseURL || ('https://' + instance + '.salesforce.com');
var proxyURL = baseURL ? (baseURL + proxy) : proxy;

var client = new forcetk.Client();
client.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}', 'v35.0', instanceURL);
client.proxyUrl = proxyURL;
```