# AngularJS app in Community

Tags: community, angular

Is it possible to build an AngularJS app for Community user?

I have followed [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/mobile/getting-started/html5#angularjs) and successfully setup an AngularJS app for internal user. However when I want to move it to Community, the browser popup query error. From my investigation, it should be the wrong path for the proxy that is used for overcoming cross domain problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a number of AngularJS apps in a community. You would need to post your code if you want help troubleshooting. Also, what cross domain problem are you speaking of?

Comment: Did you use AngularForce to call SFDC REST API? I think AngularForce does not support community's domain.

Comment: I am just using the demo code from the mobile pack https://developer.salesforce.com/en/mobile/getting-started/html5#angularjs

Comment: Possible link with this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50227/is-forcetk-accessible-in-communities